# SQL - Getting specific rows by complicated condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| ItemCode1 | ItemCode2 | Value |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| X1        | Y1        |     1 |
| X2        | Y1        |    50 |
| X3        | Y3        |     1 |
| X4        | Y4        |    20 |
| X5        | Y4        |     1 |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

And I'd like to select 1 ItemCode1 for each distinct ItemCode2, based on the highest value. I.E, the output table should look like:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| ItemCode1 | ItemCode2 | Value |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
| X2        | Y1        | 50    |
| X3        | Y3        | 1     |
| X4        | Y4        | 20    |
+-----------+-----------+-------+
```

I know it should be quite easy but for some reason, I can't get this one...
Help would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all rows where value = max(value) for the ItemCode2.

```
select ItemCode1, ItemCode2, Value 
from tablename t1
where Value = (select max(Value)
               from tablename t2
               where t1.ItemCode2 = t2.ItemCode2)
```

Note that if several rows have same max value, they will all be returned.

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.itemcode1, t1.itemcode2, t1.value
from your_table t1
join
(
  select max(value) mvalue, itemcode2
  from your_table
  group by itemcode2
) t2 on t1.value = t2.mvalue 
    and t1.itemcode2 = t2.itemcode2
```

Comment: As I understand it, OP is asking for the column VALUE's max.

Comment: @juergend Thanks, It works! (Just need to change t to t2 on the last row). Jarth got it 1st and I think it's the most elegant solution. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the record with the highest value, then select just this one record in an outer query:

```
SELECT ItemCode1, ItemCode2, Value
FROM (
   SELECT ItemCode1, ItemCode, Value, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemCode2 ORDER BY Value DESC) rn
   FROM MyTable ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If there are more than one records having the same max value and you want all of these records returned then you have to replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`.

Comment: Just need to move the left parenthesis for the PARTITION BY, it should be inside. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my submission. According to a comparison of the execution plans, this should execute a good half again faster than performing a subquery. The hash join is removed.

```
with
List( ItemCode1, ItemCode2, Value )as(
    select 'X1', 'Y1',  20 union all
    select 'X2', 'Y1',  50 union all
    select 'X3', 'Y3',   1 union all
    select 'X4', 'Y4',  20 union all
    select 'X5', 'Y4',  20 union all
    select 'X6', 'Y4',  50 union all
    select 'X7', 'Y4',  75
),
Partial( ItemCode1, ItemCode2, Value, rnk )as(
    select l.ItemCode1, l.ItemCode2, l.Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() over( partition by l.ItemCode2 order by l.Value desc ) rnk
    from list l
)
select  ItemCode1, ItemCode2, Value
from    Partial
where   rnk = 1;
```

As you see, I've added some extra data rows. Can't have too much test data!